# writing a left join as a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I put this left join query as a subquery instead?

```
SELECT d.department, COUNT(e.employeeid)
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN employee e 
   ON d.id = e.employeeid
GROUP BY d.department
ORDER BY d.department;
```

This is what I've tried, but doesn't work.

```
SELECT d.department
FROM department AS d
HAVING COUNT(e.employeeid) > 1
(
SELECT COUNT(e.employeeid)
FROM employee AS e
WHERE d.id = e.employeeid
);
```

Comment: What results exactly are you trying to achieve? Subqueries are generally less efficient than equivalent joins. If you just wanted departments with more than one employee, you could just use the HAVING from the second query in the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a correlated sub-query in the select list.

```
SELECT d.department,
       (select COUNT(e.employeeid) from employee e where d.id = e.employeeid)
FROM department d
ORDER BY d.department
```

Perhaps you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate rows.

**Edit:** That join condition seems a bit strange. Shouldn't it be `d.id = e.departmentid` or similar?

Comment: Thanks, your post helped me out so much. I finally got it working. I suppose that join statement is a bit weird? I'm not sure about it myself, but it works.